# Reference request: Knots that don't come from Milnor spheres.

Tags: algebraic-curves, knot-theory, singularity, singularity-theory, knot-invariants

In Milnor's book "Hypersurface singularities" He discusses shortly knots that arrive as Milnor spheres of algebraic curves, i.e knots that are the intersection of a $3$ sphere around a singular point of a complex algebraic curve in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$.

I am looking for references on these types of knots. Specifically, I am interested in their properties and in examples of knots that are not this type, together with proof. Preferably statements about knot invariants of these knots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knots and, more generally, links appearing as in links of algebraic hypersurface singularities in  ${\mathbb C}^3$ are called **algebraic**. They are rare among all (tame) knots and links in $S^3$. They can be described as obtained using torus knots and links via certain constructions (cabling). For instance, they can never be hyperbolic and, hence, the simplest example of a non-algebraic knot is the [figure eight knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot_(mathematics)).

You can find a detailed study of algebraic links (with proofs of the above statements) in the book

D.Eisenbud, W.Neumann, [Three-Dimensional Link Theory and Invariants of Plane Curve Singularities](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691083810/three-dimensional-link-theory-and-invariants-of-plane-curve), Princeton University Press, 1986.